# How to override TTabControl OnKeyDown?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a `TTabControl` on a form, and I would like that if the **tabs** (tab header) is focused, and when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd>, it will focus on the right-most tab. Sadly, `TTabControl` doesn't have an `OnKeyDown` event, unlike `TEdit`. How can I implement a custom `OnKeyDown` event?

Comment: Why would that happen surely ctrl+right arrow should activate the next page to the right

Comment: as of now, if I press arrow_right, it goes to the next right tab. This is the default behavior, and I want that if user press ctrl+arrow_right it will go to the last right tab

Comment: Why don't your users simply use `Home` and `End` button to move between first and last Tab? Why invent new ways of achieving this if standard `TabControl` already has the needed functionality present?

Comment: Do you hate your users? They learn how tab and page controls work and can use the same shortcuts in all programs. But then they use yours and it's different. Are you trying to make life hard for your users?

Comment: I very strongly agree with SilverWarrior and David Heffernan. In Microsoft Windows, you have used Home and End to navigate to the first and the last tab for decades.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the way I presented my problem is just the tip of the ice berg. I am maintaining legacy codes and its hard for me to actually describe what I want to achieve, but answers provided will guide me to address my actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass the TabControl's `WindowProc` property to do whatever you want with its received messages directly, eg:

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    TabControl1: TTabControl;
    ...
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  private
    OldTabWndProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure MyTabWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
    ...
end;
```

```
procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OldTabWndProc := TabControl1.WindowProc;
  TabControl1.WindowProc := MyTabWndProc;
end;

procedure TMyForm.MyTabWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_KEYDOWN then
  begin
    ...
  end;
  OldTabWndProc(Message);
end;
```